# How to get child entity values from Core Data?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I had two tables in core data. one is TblContacts and second TblAddresses. TblAddresses is the child of TblContact. Now I want all addressIds of TblAddresses in selected contacts. I can get addressIds with for each loop. But I want to know the best way. See the below code how I get the contactsIds. Same way I need AddressIds. Is there is a way or not?

```
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

    NSEntityDescription *entityDesc = [NSEntityDescription  entityForName:@"TblContact" inManagedObjectContext:appDelegate.managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entityDesc];
    fetchRequest.resultType = NSDictionaryResultType;
    fetchRequest.propertiesToFetch = @[@"contactID"];
    NSArray *contactsArray1 = [[[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:[appDelegate.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil]]valueForKey:@"contactID"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Better provide one to many relation mapping (Contacts to Address). So it will be easy to fetch contacts along with address.